# Send mails laravel5 with gmail in local

Tags: email, laravel, gmail

I have a problem sending emails

I have the following code in Laravel

The file mail.php

```
return [ 
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => ['address' => 'email@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Kiko'],
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => env('email@gmail.com'),
    'password' => env(''),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

Log

```
[2015-05-29 13:27:48] local.DEBUG: Message-ID: <673a61b16f681371f9daa76f839527bd@localhost>
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 13:27:48 +0000
Subject: Welcome to My Website
From: Kiko <email@gmail.com>
To: email@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And the .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME='email@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD=''
```

If in the file .env I change .log to smpt the log returns this message

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

[2015-05-29 13:40:40] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in C:\xampp3\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Anybody could help me to see error ?

Comment: Did you enabled `Less secure apps` in Gmail control panel? If you don't you can not connect to your gmail account via smtp.

Comment: Yes , I active this option in my panel and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are using different ports in mail.php and .env